# Pandas KeyError(key)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access singular cells utilising column and index in pandas and I am getting the following error whenever referencing the .csv file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<me>\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    players[i].name = str(fileIn['playerName'][i])
  File "C:\Users\<me>\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1007, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\<me>\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1116, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\<me>\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 349, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'playerName'
```

My .csv file's contents are as follows:

```
playerName,survivability
Tyler,1
Kylie,12
```

and here is my script:

```
import pandas

players = []

class Player:
   name = ""

fileIn = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/<me>/Downloads/input.csv')

for i in fileIn:

   players.append(Player())
   
   players[i].name = str(fileIn['playerName'][i])

   print("Player " + str(i + 1) + "'s profile is complete.")
```

The survivability column is required for the complete project but produces the same error so I've omitted that segment of the program, but will need to be able to access it in the final product.

I see that this question has been asked time and time again, but I've not found an answer that works. I apologise if I've missed something and would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction if you are aware of one.

Comment: Before `for-loop`, check `print(fileIn.columns)` to accessible columns/keys

Comment: You're iterating over column names. Instead of `for i in fileIn:` use `for i in fileIn.iterrows():` or `for i in fileIn.itertuples():`

Comment: Did you leave out the step of filling in the `players` list with `Player` instances?

Comment: I used Shaik's tip and got confirmation that I was using the proper column names (Thank you). I then followed Vitalizzare's advice which was a success in resolving the immediate issue. And yes, Barmar, I did forget that part. I will make an edit to solve that issue. Thank you all for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

class Player:
   name = ""
   
fileIn = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/<me>/Downloads/input.csv")


players = []
for i in fileIn.iterrows():   
   players.append(Player())
   players[i[0]].name = i[1]['playerName']
   print("Player " + str(i[0] + 1) + "'s profile is complete.")
```

Comment: After implementing this solution I found that the result was that every `Player()` object had its `name` variable changed to match the last result (with the example input file, both resulting `player[x].name` variables were == 'Kylie'. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, please change the code as below.

players = []
for i in fileIn.iterrows():   
   players.append(Player())
   players[i[0]].name = i[1]['playerName']
   print("Player " + str(i[0] + 1) + "'s profile is complete.")

Comment: I have edited the code in the solution box.